# React: Deleting URL parameters not working properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wrote my own router because I want my React app to support a split screen. The split screen is optional. The URL looks like this (left and right are the respective keys for the splitscreens).

`http://myapp.com/app/?left.view.name=home&right.view.name=about`

Parameters can also be added to the views.
`http://myapp.com/app/?left.view.name=home&right.view.name=about&right.view.params.param1=value1`

My problem now is that I have to delete the parameters related to a split screen. But this doesn't really work.

```
const url = new URL(window.location.href);
console.log(url.searchParams.toString());

url.searchParams.forEach((_, key) => {
    console.log(`key=${key}`);
    if (!key.startsWith(`${frameKey}.`)) { // frameKey is the key of the splitscreen
        return;
    }
    url.searchParams.delete(key);
});
```

**EXAMPLE:**

```
http://myapp.com/app/?left.view.name=home&left.view.params.param1=value1
```

When I call my function to remove all URL parameters that are related to the left screen,
this happens:

**OUTPUT:**

```
left.view.name=home&left.view.params.param1=value1
key=left.view.name
```

As you can see, the URL is output correctly (`url.searchParams.toString()`) in `console.log`. However, the subsequent call of the function does not return all keys .

If I replace

```
url.searchParams.forEach((_, key) => {
```

with

```
new URL(window.location.href).searchParams.forEach((_, key) => {
```

it works.

What is the problem here?

Comment: I don't think it's related to react, but the behaviour is indeed weird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been working on this problem for a few hours now. Sometimes you can become a little blind when it comes to your own code. The behavior was so strange because I deleted keys during the iteration.

The easiest alternative is of course to create a list containing all the keys to be deleted and then iterate over this list and delete the keys from the original object.

With the kind help of Chat GPT.

```
        const url = new URL(window.location.href);
        const keysToDelete: string[] = [];

        url.searchParams.forEach((_, key) => {
            if (!key.startsWith(`${frameKey}.`)) {
                return;
            }
            keysToDelete.push(key);
        });

        for (const keyToDelete of keysToDelete) {
            url.searchParams.delete(keyToDelete);
        }
```